# Cannot get value for first column on a selected row in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to get the value of a the first column on a selected row that the user double clicks on in a listview found in my WPF application. Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error message:

`Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'PlotList' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem'.`

Any idea how I can fix this? This is my code so far:

```
    private void PlotListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var lvi = (ListViewItem)PlotListView.SelectedItems[0];
        MessageBox.Show(lvi.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What type of data is bound to PlotListView?

Comment: @Sam the error states `PlotList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(PlotListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text);
```

Comment: I think the first subitem is the second column

Answer (score 1):

ListView.SelectedItems return the object you add to the ListView.Items.It can't be converted to ListViewItem.ListViewItem is a container of item in ListView.
From its inheritance hierarchy, we can find it's a Control